# excel macro to remove duplicates column by column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet (Sheet1) that contains 27 columns (A:AA). Each column has product names that start with one alphabetic letter, column AA contains names that start with a number. The number of names of products in Sheet1 exceeds 1.5 million. I have implemented the following macro to sort each column's data in ascending way (a-z), and it works fine. Can this script be modified to also remove duplicate names per column till the last column (AA)? There's no comparison between columns, it is just each column on its own to be sorted and have duplicate values (names of products) removed.

```
Sub SortProductNames()
Dim rCell As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
For Each rCell In Range("A2:AA2") 
    rCell.EntireColumn.RemoveDuplicates 1 'added as recommended by KazJaw
    rCell.EntireColumn.Sort Key1:=rCell(2, 1), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Next rCell
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Highly appreciating any assistance with this matter.

Comment: Try to enter this line: **`rCell.EntireColumn.RemoveDuplicates 1`** right after **`For Each rCell In Range("A2:AA2")`**

Comment: Yes KazJaw, it did it successfully. Thank you very much for your prompt and professional answer. All the best.

Comment: Utilizing the script in question after entering suggested line by KazJaw works successfully, but I noticed it does not eliminate blank cells. So I find gaps in all columns despite they are sorted and no duplicate found. Any opinion to fix this fault?

Comment: but you have blanked cells at the bottom? show complete code as edit to your question

Comment: Complete code is updated with recommended addition. Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but I need something more to understand your problem. I need a pictures which show what you have 'before' and 'after'. If I make simple simulation where columns have few empty cells there is nothing unusual... data range is continuous in each column. You can upload pictures anywhere and place links here in comments

Comment: Thank you very much KazJaw. I think I know now what caused that problem. I included this sub in a master macro that runs three macros one after the other. So data were not properly "stacked" as expected through the master macro. When I ran sub sortProductNames on its own, it did sort and remove dups and left no empty cells!! So it is now taken off the master macro and will be run on its own. Once again, thank you very much KazJaw for your sincere cooperation.